# Need to convert OUTER JOIN with multiple "AND"

Tags: sql, esqueleto

I have this raw sql I'd like to convert to Esqueleto. It should bring all the `group`s that user ID 1, isn't registered to via the `group_membership` table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM group
LEFT OUTER JOIN group_membership
  ON (group.id = group_membership.group_id AND group_membership.user_id=1)
  WHERE group_membership.group_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm able to see some related info on how to do the `IS NULL`, but still stuck on the multiple `AND` - https://github.com/prowdsponsor/esqueleto/issues/50#issuecomment-37094450

Comment: And the `AND` inside the `on` answered here -- https://github.com/prowdsponsor/esqueleto/issues/126#issuecomment-172010758

Answer (score 0):

And here is the answer I gathered from different issues:

```
getGroups userId = do
    runDB
        . E.select
        . E.from $ \(group `E.LeftOuterJoin` groupMembership) -> do
            E.on $ E.just (group ^. GroupId) E.==. (groupMembership ?. GroupMembershipGroupId) &&.
                   (groupMembership ?. GroupMembershipUserId) E.==. E.just (E.val userId)
            E.where_ $ E.isNothing (groupMembership ?. GroupMembershipGroupId)
            return
              ( group ^. GroupId
              , group ^. GroupTitle
              )
```